# React-Konva animation de-renders next rectangle when using shift()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, konvajs, react-konva

I am trying to create an animation to simulate a queue data structure using react-konva, the code works as intended when I use it as a stack with `pop()` and `push()` but when I use `shift()` to remove the first element the next element in the queue gets de-rendered from the canvas along with the first. I've tried using `slice()` and manually looping each item from the old queue into the new queue but nothing seems to be working.

I'm keeping track of changes in the queue using a `useEffect` and `useRef` to store a ref of each rectangle in an array.

The enqueue animation works fine and runs as intended

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (enqueueState) {
        setEnqueueState(prevState => !prevState)
        animateNewBlock()
    };
}, [enqueueState])    

const animateNewBlock = () => {
    let rect = localQueueArray[localQueueArray.length - 1];
    let array = headQueue;
    if (rectRef.current !== null) array.push(rectRef.current);
    setHeadQueue(array);
    rectRef.current?.to({
        x: rect.posX
    })
    setQueueArrayCount(prevState => (prevState + 1));
}
```

The problem is the dequeue animation which de-renders two rectangles instead of one

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (dequeueState) {
        setDequeueState(prevState => !prevState)
        animateOldBlock()
    };
}, [dequeueState])

const animateOldBlock = () => {
    let newHead = [...headQueue]
    let rectRef = newHead.shift();
    let array = [...queueArray]
    rectRef?.to({
        x: (queueCanvasWidth + 200)
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
        setQueueArrayCount(prevState => (prevState - 1));
        setLocalQueueArray(array)
        setHeadQueue(newHead)
    }, 500)
}
```

This is how the rectangles are rendered on the page

```
<div className={`canvas-container ${canvasTheme}`} ref={canvasRef}>
            <Stage width={canvasRef.current?.clientWidth} height={canvasRef.current?.clientHeight}>
                {(localQueueArray.length > 0) && <Layer>
                    <Text
                        x={headTagPosX}
                        y={headTagPosY}
                        text={"Head"}
                        fontSize={20}
                        fontStyle="bold"
                        fill={rectColor}
                        ref={textRef}
                    />
                    {localQueueArray.map((object: QueueType, index: number) => {
                        return (
                            <Rect
                                x={-200}
                                y={object.posY}
                                height={object.height}
                                width={object.width}
                                fill={object.color}
                                strokeWidth={1}
                                key={index}
                                ref={rectRef}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </Layer>}
            </Stage>
        </div>
```

The above system works when you used to simulate a stack.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the key which uses the index of the array, someone explained to me the ref re-attaches to the new element at the same index.